How to I split a date column and a result column into new columns for multiple observations per ID?
I would like to spread the date column into new columns (Date 1, Date 2, Date 3, etc.) for each observation in chronological order.  I would also like to add a column with the corresponding result My data looks like this:
> CV
       Name Accession   MRN  Collected   Result
1 Doe, John       123 55555 2022-01-05 Detected
2 Doe, John       234 55555 2022-01-06 Negative
3 Doe, John       345 55555 2022-01-07 Detected
4 Doe, Jane       456 66666 2022-01-08 Negative
5 Doe, Jane       567 66666 2022-01-09 Negative
6 Doe, Jane       678 66666 2022-01-20 Negative

I would like it to look like this
Name           MRN        Date_1      Result_1      Date_2      Result_2     Date_3    Result_3        

Doe, John     55555     2022-01-05    Detected     2022-01-06   Negative   2022-01-07  Detected
Doe, Jane     66666     2022-01-08    Negative     2022-01-09   Negative   2022-01-20  Negative     

I think I may need to use the accession number as a key but I'm not really sure how to perform this?
data
Name <- c("Doe, John", "Doe, John", "Doe, John", "Doe, Jane", 
          "Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane")
Accession <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678)
MRN <- c(55555, 55555, 55555, 66666, 66666, 66666)
Collected <- c("2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08", 
              "2022-01-09", "2022-01-20")
Result <- c("Detected", "Negative", "Detected", "Negative", 
            "Negative", "Negative")
CV <- data.frame(Name, Accession, MRN, Collected, Result)


You could replace the Accession by a running id (1, 2, 3, ...) and use reshape.
> CV |> 
+   transform(Accession=ave(Name, Name, FUN=seq_along)) |> 
+   reshape(idvar=c('Name', 'MRN'), timevar='Accession', direction='wide')
       Name   MRN Collected.1 Result.1 Collected.2 Result.2 Collected.3 Result.3
1 Doe, John 55555  2022-01-05 Detected  2022-01-06 Negative  2022-01-07 Detected
4 Doe, Jane 66666  2022-01-08 Negative  2022-01-09 Negative  2022-01-20 Negative

If you want the column to be named Date instead of Collected add a line that does the cosmetics.
> CV |> 
+   transform(Accession=ave(Name, Name, FUN=seq_along)) |> 
+   reshape(idvar=c('Name', 'MRN'), timevar='Accession', direction='wide') |> 
+   {\(.) setNames(., sub('Collected', 'Date', names(.)))}()
       Name   MRN     Date.1 Result.1     Date.2 Result.2     Date.3 Result.3
1 Doe, John 55555 2022-01-05 Detected 2022-01-06 Negative 2022-01-07 Detected
4 Doe, Jane 66666 2022-01-08 Negative 2022-01-09 Negative 2022-01-20 Negative


Data:
> dput(CV)
structure(list(Name = c("Doe, John", "Doe, John", "Doe, John", 
"Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane"), Accession = c(123, 234, 
345, 456, 567, 678), MRN = c(55555, 55555, 55555, 66666, 66666, 
66666), Collected = c("2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", 
"2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-20"), Result = c("Detected", 
"Negative", "Detected", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


Pretty sure there are prior questions on SO that answer this shape of question, but I didn't find in a cursory search. In any case, here's what I usually do:

Note the # observation per Name.
Get the columns we want, with the names we want
pivot_wider using the # observation and the data columns we want


library(tidyverse)
CV |>
  mutate(obs = row_number(), .by = c(Name, MRN)) |>
  rename(Date = Collected) |>
  select(-Accession) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = obs, values_from = c(Date:Result), 
              names_vary = "slowest")

Result
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  Name        MRN Date_1     Result_1 Date_2     Result_2 Date_3     Result_3
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>   
1 Doe, John 55555 2022-01-05 Detected 2022-01-06 Negative 2022-01-07 Detected
2 Doe, Jane 66666 2022-01-08 Negative 2022-01-09 Negative 2022-01-20 Negative

